# how to use awk to filter newline as record seperator and field seperator

Tags: awk

I have the following file :

```
Field1

   UNIX - System V

Field2

   32 bit

Field3

   No
```

here field operator is double line and record operator is also a double line. I want output as:

```
Field1  UNIX - System V
Field2 32 bit
```

On writing the following command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="\n"; RS="\n\n"} {print $1 $2}' ctemp.txt
```

I am not getting my desired output.

Comment: Welcome to SO, special thanks for showing your efforts in code. Could you please edit your post and wrap your samples in CODE TAGS so that we could clearly read it?

Comment: I have wrapped your samples in CODE TAGS now, please feel free to edit in case they are not looking as per your wanted samples, edit them to look alike your desired samples please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NF{printf "%s%s", $0, ((++c)%2 ? OFS : ORS)}' file
Field1    UNIX - System V
Field2    32 bit
Field3    No
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following, tested with provided samples and written with GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v FS="\n" -v RS="^$" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=4){print $i,$(i+2)}}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** OR above will NOT deal with spaces coming in starting of lines, in case you want to remove those spaces like we have before (UNIX - System V) then try following.

```
awk -v FS="\n" -v RS="^$" '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=4){
    sub(/^ +/,"",$i)
    sub(/^ +/,"",$(i+2))
  print $i,$(i+2)
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Should work in a NON GNU `awk` too, tested and written with provided samples by OP.

```
awk '
value==""{
  value=$0
  next
}
NF && value{
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  print value,$0
  value=""
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the first part worked fine. I was looking for the same. Thanks Again.

Comment: @mishamehra, Your welcome, cheers and happy learning on this GREAT site SO.